# implementing video chat app in android

Tags: android, video-streaming

I have a school project. I need to write a video conversation android app. Two client devices should connect each other over server in real time. And server must be written by myself too. So far I have not developed such complex app. I am not familiar with server concepts. I did some search and couldn't find any useful source. So I am asking you where should I begin. By the way server can be developed with any language.

Answer (score 0):

This [project](https://github.com/justaddwater71/FirstResponder) from github might give you an idea. I think the server is written with ruby.